# Usage of bitwise or to run functions inside if statement

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where I want to make sure that some or all functions used inside an if statement are run regardless of the statement is already true. I know I can use an bitwise operator for this.

```
function test1() {
    console.log('called1');
    return true;
}
function test2() {
    console.log('called2');
    return false;
}

if(test1() | test2()) {
    console.log('done');
}
// called 1
// called 2
// done

if(test1() | test2() | test1() || test2()) {
    console.log('done');
}
// called 1
// called 2
// called 1
// done
```

Is this a correct usage for the bitwise or operator though? I can't find this usage described anywhere.

Comment: I don't see the point of this. The bitwise operator `|` joins the bits of the returned value of each function. My understanding is that the booleans behave as `0` or `1`, so the `console.log` inside of each if will be executed as long as one of the functions returns a truthy value. If you want to execute functions, just call them :S

Comment: @bgusach: That *is* the point: The OP wants to call them, all four of them, and branch if *any* of them returned `true`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok, if that is the intent, this makes sense. I would however do something like calling all functions and then analyzing the results to branch if necessary.

Comment: @bgusach That is a option but this looks more organized to me and needs a lot less lines of code. You can really go nuts with it while keeping it organized. Example: if((test1() | test2() || test2b()) | test3() | (test4() || test4b())){}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a correct usage for the bitwise or operator though?

It's *valid*, because your functions return values (in your case, booleans) which can be successfully coerced to useful numeric values (`false` => `0`, `true` => `1`), which can be OR'd together, and which when OR'd together do give you a value that you can usefully coerce back to boolean.

As for *correct*, well, if I saw it in code, I would tend to think it was a typo and that you intended to write `||` instead. You'd at least have to comment it to flag up the intention of avoiding short-circuiting.

But it's perfectly valid and not pushing the edge of anything, it's clearly-specified behavior.